# Windows 8 item Background (Javascript)

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm using the Javascript template for making a Windows 8 App with Visual Studio.

Setting the background image for one of my items with backgroundImage: : "images/breeds/sheep.jpg" doesn't seem to be working.

```
{ group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 5", subtitle: "", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: : "images/breeds/sheep.jpg"}
```

The location of the image is relative to the root of the file because I assumed the app runs from default.html.

The image shows as a broken link. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Noticed the following error

```
The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://8a32c4d0-abb1-413b-8989-339848463d6c/images/breeds/Berrichon_Du_Cher.jpg because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ms-appx` protocol for specifying local files. In your example, you could change the image path to something like `"ms-appx:///images/breeds/sheep.jpg"`. You can get some more information on the protocols available for file access in [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx).

Alternatively, you can just put a / in front of your path to make sure it is being resolved from the project's root. IE, `"/images/breeds/sheep.jpg"`

Comment: Thanks but no luck with either method.

Comment: Are the images actually included in your visual studio solution? I don't see any reason why you would not be able to access them this way if they're being copied.

Comment: I copied them into the folder. When I view them from the 'solution explorer' I see the folder but it's in dotted line.

Comment: Try right clicking on the folder, going to the Add menu item, and clicking the "Existing Item..." option. From there you can select the images to add to that folder. If they're added in the solution explorer, they should be copying properly.